# How the double pointer is actually working in reverse of linked list?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, double-pointer

I had done the reverse of linked list using recursion, but how the pointer actually working a bit confused.
If I swap statements 1 and 2 in the below code the program will not run Why? Because I assume `(*head)->next = nullptr` will set `*temp = nullptr` so there is no meaning of `(*temp)->next = *head`, but if this true then in the below code even after statement 1 `(*head)->next` is set to nullptr so it should set the *temp equals to nullptr and according to that it should not reverse the linked list but actually the code reverse the linked list How?

```
void push(struct node*& tail, int v)
{
    struct node* newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = v;
    newNode->next = tail;

    tail = newNode;
}

void reverse_ll3(struct node* *rootAddress, struct node* *head, struct node* *temp)
{

    if(!(*temp))
    {
        *rootAddress = *head;
        return;
    }
    reverse_ll3(rootAddress, &((*head)->next), &((*temp)->next));
    
    (*temp)->next = *head; // --------------1
    (*head)->next = nullptr; // --------------2
}

int main()
{
struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* curr;

    push(head, 60);
    push(head, 50);
    push(head, 40);
    push(head, 30);
    push(head, 20);
    push(head, 10);
    
    print_list(head);
    cout << endl;
    
    curr = head;
    reverse_ll3(&head,&curr,&(curr->next));
    
    print_list(head);
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: C++ is not C. Please don't spam tags.

Comment: `&*temp` is the same as `temp`, and `(*head)->next` is the same as `*temp`.

Comment: Yes C++ is not C but it was more about the pointers working which is common to both languages. C and C++ both tags can be added I guess as pointers are available in both

Comment: No they can't, because C and C++ **are not** the same language. The fact that one derived from the other in the past is orthogonal of this. If Java had pointers, you would not add the java tag because it would be obvious it doesn't work the same. In other words, C and C++ being now two completely separate and distinct languages, you have no guarantee that common syntaxes do behave the same (if it did, there would not be two separate languages at first). I'm not saying pointers are not implemented the same, I'm just saying you can't assume it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
Initially, the linked list in main function is:

```
10|e0 -> 20|d0 -> 30|c0 -> 40|b0 -> 50|a0 -> 60|q0 -> null 
-----    -----    -----    -----    -----    -----    -----
x0       e0       d0       c0       b0       a0       q0
```

where `e0,d0...q0` are next node address

Let `x0,e0,d0,...q0` are stored in following address:
`e8, f4, e4, d4, c4, b4, a4` i.e

```
x0  e0  d0  c0  b0  a0  q0
--  --  --  --  --  --  --
e8  f4  e4  d4  c4  b4  a4
```

Let curr address be *e10*, so by curr = head, *e10* also contain *x0*

I am passing the `e8(&head), e10(&curr), f4(&(curr->next))` to reverse_ll3

when `temp = a4 then (!(*a4)) => (!(q0)) is true (q0 is nullptr)`
will execute the if condition
rootAddress contain *e8*, head contain *b4*
`*rootAddress = *head; i.e *e8 = *b4 => *b4 is a0` 
 *e8* now contain *a0* contents i.e *60|q0*

now recursion will unwind
1st unwind
`(*temp)->next = *head` here temp contains *b4*, head contains *c4*
`*b4 = a0, *c4 = b0`
`(*b4)->next = *c4* is a0->next = b0`
`a0->next` is  *q0* which is stored in *a4* so *a4* contents *q0* will be replaced by *b0* i.e *a0* now contains *60|b0* and *a4* contains *b0*
`(*head)->next = nullptr`
`(*c4)->next = b0->next = nullptr`, so now *a0* will be replaced by *nullptr* i.e *b0* now contains *50|null* and *b4* contains *a0*

2nd unwind
here temp contains *c4*, head contains *d4* 
`(*c4)->next = (*d4)` 
`(b0)->next  = c0`
Similarly *a0* will be replaced by *c0* i.e now *b0* contains *50|c0* and *b4* contains *c0*
**Note**: Since *a4* contains *b0*(previously *b0* contains *50|null*, now null is replaced by *c0*) and *b0* contains *50|c0* this implicitly creates link from *a0(60|b0)* to *b0(50|c0)*
`(*d4)->next = c0->next = nullptr` now *b0* will be replaced by *nullptr* i.e *c0* now contains *40|null* and *c4* contains *b0*

Similarly for other nodes same steps are going on finally *e0* will be *nullptr*

**Note**: one more improvement we can do here, we can even remove the `(*head)->next = nullptr` from reverse_ll3 and add
`curr->next = nullptr` in main function after reverse_ll3 function call because at the end `curr->next(e0)` need to be *nullptr*.

Comment: Is this part of your question or is it the answer?

Comment: Initially, I was facing difficulty in understanding the execution of the above code but later I figured out how the code is working so posted my explanation